# How to capture rtp stream from webrtc then convert it to hls to broadcast to client?

Tags: webrtc, streaming, http-live-streaming

How to capture rtp stream from webrtc then convert it to hls to broadcast to client ?
I want to receive rtp from webrtc in browser via media server (eg kurento ... ) then convert it to hls stream. User can use hlsEndpoint to play.

WebRTC -> RTP -> HLS

What is the correct way?
My aim is to create a live stream app that supports push streams using webrtc , i'm working with rtmp , i want webrtc as an additional option.

Tks all.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a media server to covert WebRTC to Live Streaming like RTMP, HTTP-FLV or HLS, please read [this wiki](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/wiki/v4_EN_WebRTC#rtc-to-rtmp).

Because the WebRTC is not only RTP, but also need to transcode the audio from opus to aac, and there is something like the jitter-buffer, NACK or packet out-of-order to handle.

For live streaming, the RTMP is the de-facto standard in live streaming industry, so if you covert WebRTC to RTMP, you got everything, like transcoding by FFmpeg, forwarding to YouTube, or DVR to file, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, allow me to ask a little more, I've been looking through SRS but don't understand how the user can push the webrtc stream to the server, for example I want to integrate it into my website (via how which connection) ? Thank you very much for your suggestion

Comment: Please follow the wiki to [publish rtc and play by rtmp](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/wiki/v4_EN_WebRTC#rtc-to-rtmp), you could also join the community by [discord](https://discord.gg/yZ4BnPmHAd)