# Live video Call(Peer to Peer Connection Via WebRTC) to broadcast to everyone by RTMP like Instagram

Tags: python, webrtc, video-streaming, rtmp

I want to **broadcast** a video call to everyone who can see that person who is on call the same thing does on Instagram.

I have done **WebRTC** with **WebSocket** in python and its works like a charm, also done **RTMP** live streaming with the OBS system to HLS, DASH, and RTMP URL as well and it's all in the live server.

It will be appreciated if guided on how to broadcast that live video call to everyone via RTMP.

Comment: You could use OBS to capture the video call, and covert to RTMP as live streaming. Or you could covert each video call to RTMP stream and merge them by FFmpeg. Do you want to build the whole system by yourself? What's the client, H5 or mobile?

Comment: Yes, I want into mobile application H5 as well, @Winlin

Comment: Seems you have covert WebRTC to RTMP? If you want to deliver RTMP to viewers, you could covert RTMP to HLS. Use a video tag to play the HLS stream, quiet simple.

Comment: Yes, that's true! I need that WebRTC to HLS/RTMP because web can't deliver direct to RTMP, web has just option of webRTC.

Comment: OK, please read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70615587/17679565